# Is there no default drag and drop behavior in an e4 application created by e(fx)clipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-rcp, efxclipse

I just created an e4 application by e(fx)clipse following [this tutorial](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial4), then I added two parts in my application as following screenshot.
[image]
And then when I mess around with this application, I found that these two tabs can't be drag and drop. Theoretically speaking, every window/view should be able to be drag and drop in a SWT UI based e4 application. Can anyone tell me how to make window/view drag and drop behavior possible in such an application? Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and drop is not part of the core of e4.

You must add the appropriate DnD addon to the Add-ons list in the Application.e4xmi to get drag and drop.

For JavaFX this is `org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench.renderers.base.addons.DnDAddon` (full entry in the Application.e4xmi should be `bundleclass://org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench.renderers.base/org‌​.eclipse.fx.ui.workb‌​ench.renderers.base.‌​addons.DnDAddon`). You may also need the cleanup addon `bundleclass://org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench.renderers.base/org‌​.eclipse.fx.ui.workb‌​ench.renderers.base.‌​addons.CleanUpAddon`

For SWT it is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDAddon`

Comment: I tried adding `bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDAddon` into Add-on in the `Application.e4xmi` file, however I got [this error](http://pastebin.com/42PHTCpL) when I was running my app again.

Comment: It turns out that the DnD addon is specific to the UI toolkit you are using. I have updated the answer with the JavaFX addon.

Comment: ok, now I have another [error](http://pastebin.com/ukwpqTcX) :( it tells that can't retrieve `org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench.renderers.base.addons.DnDAddon`, but I did add `org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench.renderers.base` into dependencies.

Comment: Make sure the full entry for the addon is `bundleclass://org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench.renderers.base/org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench.renderers.base.addons.DnDAddon` you probably also need the cleanup addon `bundleclass://org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench.renderers.base/org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench.renderers.base.addons.CleanUpAddon`

Comment: That log is still using org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDAddon